# Refresh Data in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, frameworks, entity

When I open my program and try to get all my users the following code will be executed:

```
    public static List<User> GetAllUsers()
    {
        return db.Users.OrderBy(x => x.ID).ToList();
    }
```

If I go to my SQL Server Management Studio and change some value and redo GetAllUsers(); the data is still the same.
Is there any way to refresh the data? Best would be to even refresh all (I have other classes in my DbContext) so i actually reload everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this question
[How to Refresh DbContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18169970/how-do-i-refresh-dbcontext)

But i suggest not to use a static dbcontext,check this
 [Pros and Cons of putting a db context in static class library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14526308/pros-and-cons-of-putting-a-db-context-in-static-class-library)

Comment: I was only working with a static dbcontext so I am not sure if i can change this right now. By the way, the data refresh if i call db = new Database(); .. but i think this is not the right way to handle this, is it?

Comment: Either that,or use the Refresh method as it is shown in my first link.

Comment: That works aswell. But i think if i Dispose() my db and create it again this will work without detecting all changes. But your answer is right aswell :)

Comment: if you dispose the context and create a new one it will definitely load the latest data